# Flutter UI Row Texts Widget should Not Eclipse If Space is Available in Row

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface, text, row

I have a problem with flutter UI, I have three text widgets in a row and I want each widget to take a maximum third part of the screen width if all texts are large but at the  same time if anyone of them is small text then rest widgets/texts should not eclipse but take rest space and divide between them, As texts would be dynamic any text can be large or small,

**Let's clear again,**

If all three texts in a row are large texts then full width should be divided into three and texts should eclipse themselves as texts should be a single line text, if any of them is small text then rest space should be taken by other texts and divided between them so that instead of eclipsing texts they should take benefit of the rest space,

**What I want**

**First example**

first text **|** second text is medium **|** third text is too large so it would take a lot of the space

**Second Example**

first text is too short **|** second text is medium text **|** third text is too large so it would take a lot of space...

**Third Example**

first text will take equal space... | second text will aslo take equal space... | third text will also take equal space...

pls help your help would be appreciated

**Problem with my code**

here is my try but it limits texts to take only a third part of the screen even if any of the text is too small,

```
LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (context, constraints) => Row(
      children: [
        Container(
          constraints: BoxConstraints.loose(Size.fromWidth(constraints.maxWidth / 3)),
          color: Colors.red,
          child: const Text('large g long large',maxLines: 1,overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,),
        ),

        Container(
          constraints: BoxConstraints.loose(Size.fromWidth(constraints.maxWidth / 3)),
          color: Colors.green,
          child: const Text('Smalledtng th xt Smalled Smalledtng th xt Smalled Smalledtng th xt Smalled Smalledtng th xt Smalled',maxLines: 1,overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,),
        ),
        Container(
          constraints: BoxConstraints.loose(Size.fromWidth(constraints.maxWidth / 3)),
          color: Colors.blue,
          child: const Text('Smalledtng th xt smal text',maxLines: 1,overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,),
        ),
      ],
    ),
    ),
```

Answer (score 1):

This could be a way:

```
class MyHome extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHome({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static const textList = [
    'this is a longer text,this is a longer text,this is a longer text',
    'short',
    'another long text,another long text'
  ];
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Map<String, int> map = {};
    int width=0;
    int? flex;
    final screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    for (final text in theList) {
      final size = calcTextSize(text: text);
      map[text] = (screenWidth * size.width).ceil();
      width=width+size.width.ceil();
    }
    if (width<=screenWidth-500){
      flex=1;
    }
    return Container(
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
      color: Colors.white,
      child: Center(
        child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: map.entries
                .map(
                  (e) => Flexible(
                fit: FlexFit.tight,
                flex: flex??e.value,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                  child: Text(
                    e.key,
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    maxLines: 1,
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            )
                .toList()),
      ),
    );
  }

  Size calcTextSize({required String text, TextStyle? style}) {
    final textPainter = TextPainter(
      text: TextSpan(text: text, style: style),
      textDirection: ui.TextDirection.ltr,
      textScaleFactor: WidgetsBinding.instance.window.textScaleFactor,
    )..layout();
    return textPainter.size;
  }
}
```

If the text is same size:
[image]

If not:
[image]

Comment: this is working but not properly working as per expected, it still creates spaces between texts even if they are so small, texts are not so close to each other in result of this

Comment: I added a padding, you can delete it, than there should be no space between the one text and the other text...I edited the answer

Comment: Still has spaces and if I make all three texts large it does not divide screen width space equally into three

Comment: I tried it again... if the text has the same size they are placed evenly, if not the shorter text has less space available than the longer text...

Comment: still not working, the same issue